# Laurent's expansion confusing

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Following H.A.Priestley's Introduction to Complex Analysis, it looks like Laurent's expansion only defined at $A:=\{z:R<|z|<T\}$ where $R$ can be zero. However, I also seen questions where we are required to find the expansion for the unit disc. In which case the region cannot be put in the form $\{z:R<|z|<T\}$. So is the question equivalently asking to find the expansion in the region $\{z:0<|z|<1\}?$ I rather get the feeling two things are not equivalent.

Comment: You can have a Laurent expansion on the punctured unit disk, yes.

Comment: The "Laurent expansion on the unit disc" is better known as the "Taylor expansion".  If you want, you can simply find the Laurent expansion on the punctured disc and note whether it can be extended analytically to the unit disc by seeing whether any negative power of $z$ has a nonzero coefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facts:

1. Each holomorphic function $f : D  \to \mathbb C$ defined on an open disk $D = D(c;R) =  \{ z \in \mathbb C \mid \lvert z - c \rvert < R \}$ has a unique Taylor expansion $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (z-c)^n$ on $D$.
2. Each holomorphic function $f : A  \to \mathbb C$ defined on an open annulus $A = A(c;R,T) =  \{ z \in \mathbb C \mid R < \lvert z - c \rvert < T \}$ has a unique Laurent expansion $f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n (z-c)^n$ on $A$.

For a Laurent expansion it may of course happen that $a_n = 0$ for $n < 0$. In that case $f$ has a holomomorphic extension $F : D(c;T) \to \mathbb C$.

Thus, if you have a holomorphic function $f$ on the punctured unit disk $D^*$, it has a Laurent expansion $f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n z^n$ on $D^*$. This series has $a_n = 0$ for $n < 0$ iff $f$ is bounded. In fact, precisely when $f$ is bounded the singularity at $0$ is removable.

Comment: It depends on the domain where functions are defined. Yes, if the domain is an open disk. If functions are defined only on an annulus (or on a punctured disk), then in general no Taylor expansion exists. For example, $f(z) = 1/z$ does not have a Taylor expansion at $0$. However, also  $f(z) = \sin(z)/z$ is not defined at $z = 0$, but is has a removable singularity at this point. Therefore its Laurent expansion is actually a Taylor series.